# Terminal Applescript unable to escape quote

Tags: terminal, applescript, osascript

I've run into a strange problem when trying to include quote marks `' '` in my osascript command.

If I try and escape a normal escapable character, it works fine. Example: `osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to display dialog "Te\\st"'` A dialog box from Finder pops up with the text `Test` in it.

However, the problem occurs when I try and use apostrophes when I'm writing out full sentences. Example: `osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to display dialog "Te\'st"'` When I run this, all I'm left with is no dialog box, and the text input in terminal looking like this:

`>`

From what I know, this should by all means work, however, it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
osascript -e "tell app \"Finder\" to display dialog \"'Something' in quotes"\"
```

Answer (score 7):

Just to complement @Zero's helpful answer (which indeed does solve the problem):

Since you're using `osascript`, it is **the *shell*'s (`bash`'s) quoting rules that apply *first***:

In `bash` (or any POSIX-compatible shell), **you cannot include single quotes in a single-quoted string** - not even with escaping.

What you CAN do, however, is to **break your string into multiple pieces and simply splice in single quotes** where needed (escaped outside a quoted string as `\'`):

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to display dialog "Te'\''st"'
```

- `'tell app "Finder" to display dialog "Te'`, the first part, is followed by the escaped single quote `\'`, followed by the remainder of the string `'st"'`
- By virtue of having NO spaces between the parts, `bash` creates a *single* string that does contain the spliced-in literal `'`.

It is **generally easier to pass *single*-quoted strings to `osascript`**, since double quotes are frequently used in AppleScript and therefore have to be escaped when enclosed in a *double*-quoted string (as in the accepted answer).

In the typically infrequent event that you must pass a single quote to AppleScript, you can use the technique described in this answer.